# C++ Compile error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error

**Very specific C++ compilation syntax error that I can't figure out a solution to:** I'm fairly new to C++ and read up on functions being passed as parameters. The compile error doesn't make sense to me because I've read the code over-and-over. Please help.

**Edit**: I removed the waitpid(pid_t,int,int) and stuck with just system() commands. Thanks for the help everyone.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){
/* puts apt-get purge text into ~$ purge_e_output */
    system("sudo apt-get purge enlightenment > purge_e_output.txt");
    system("echo **Pid of apt-get**");
    system("pidof apt-get");
    try{
        pid_t waitpid(pid_t getpid("apt-get"), int *statusPtr, int WUNTRACED);
    } catch(...){}
    system("echo **REMOVING ENGLIGHTENMENT**"); 
    system("sudo apt-get purge enlightenment");
    system("pidof apt-get");
    try{
        pid_t waitpid(pid_t getpid("apt-get"), int *statusPtr, int WUNTRACED);
    } catch(...){}

/* puts apt-get autoremove text into ~$ autoremove_e_output */
    system("sudo apt-get autoremove > autoremove_e_output.txt");
    system("echo **Pid of apt-get**");
    system("pidof apt-get");
    try{
        pid_t waitpid(pid_t getpid("apt-get"), int *statusPtr, int WUNTRACED);
    } catch(...){}

    system("echo **REMOVING E DATA**"); 
    system("sudo apt-get autoremove");
    system("echo **Pid of apt-get**");
    system("pidof apt-get");
    try{
        pid_t waitpid(pid_t getpid("apt-get"), int *statusPtr, int WUNTRACED);
    } catch(...){}

/* puts apt-get autoclean text into ~$ autoclean_e_output */
    system("sudo apt-get autoclean > autoclean_e_output.txt");
    system("echo **Pid of apt-get**");
    system("pidof apt-get");
    try{
        pid_t waitpid(pid_t getpid("apt-get"), int *statusPtr, int WUNTRACED);
    } catch(...){}
    system("echo **CLEANING**");    
    system("sudo apt-get autoclean");
    system("echo **Pid of apt-get**");
    system("pidof apt-get");
    try{
        pid_t waitpid(pid_t getpid("apt-get"), int *statusPtr, int WUNTRACED);
    } catch(...){}

/* reinstall englightenment */
    system("echo **REINSTALLING**");    
    system("sudo apt-get install enlightenment");
    system("echo **Pid of apt-get**");
    system("pidof apt-get");
    try{
        pid_t waitpid(pid_t getpid("apt-get"), int *statusPtr, int WUNTRACED);
    } catch(...){}

/* logs */
    system("echo && echo Logs for wtf just happened:");
    system("echo && echo ~$ purge_e_output.txt && echo ~$ autoremove_e_output.txt && echo ~$ autoclean_e_output.txt");

}
```

**Compile error:**

```
~$ g++ JIC.cpp -o JIC

JIC.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
JIC.cpp:12: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
JIC.cpp:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
JIC.cpp:26: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
JIC.cpp:34: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
JIC.cpp:42: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
JIC.cpp:49: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
JIC.cpp:58: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
```

Comment: Are you trying to make or call the function? You can't make them inside other functions, and that isn't the proper way to call one.

Comment: when you call a function, don't specify the type of the argument. .. and 1) why do you call waitpid? 2) a shell script would be better for this task.

Comment: In addition to all that, you don't waitpid() for stuff called via system(). And I've never seen a getpid() call that takes a process name... and I think it's unlikely that waitpid() or getpid() will actually throw c++ exceptions :-)

Comment: This: `pid_t waitpid(pid_t getpid("apt-get"), int *statusPtr, int WUNTRACED);` is a syntax error. It would be helpful if you could tell us what it's supposed to do.

Comment: The `system()` call spawns *and waits* for a process to finish so you will never be able to find the process ID (the process will be gone by the time that line is reached).  If you really need to do this, please update your question.

Comment: I've removed the "[SOLVED]" from the title. The way to indicate that a question has been answered is to accept an answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. If none of the existing answers solves the problem, it's ok to post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Thankyou, I solved it by getting rid of waitpid, etc..

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense in that place:

```
pid_t waitpid(pid_t getpid("apt-get"), int *statusPtr, int WUNTRACED);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this

```
    pid_t waitpid(pid_t getpid("apt-get"), int *statusPtr, int WUNTRACED);
```

instead you need to actually create instances of the variables that you want to pass to this function. For example

```
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    int status = // set to some value that you choose
```

then you can call your function like this

```
    pid_t pid2 = waitpid(pid, &status, WUNTRACED);
```

now `pid2` is the value returned by the `waitpid` function.
I would strongly advise you to do a little more reading  - whether it be books or tutorials - as your question shows you don't yet have a strong grasp of the language. I mean absolutely no offence by that at all - just trying to help.

Comment: No offence taken, but yeah I removed waitpid, etc., and the application will just use system() commands.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
pid_t waitpid(pid_t getpid("apt-get"), int *statusPtr, int WUNTRACED);
```

looks like a function declaration, both to me and to the C++ compiler. It looks like you're trying to declare a function named `waitpid` whose return type is `pid_t`, which takes three parameters, a `pid_t`, an `int*`, and an `int`. However, the name of a parameter can't be `getpid("apt-get")`, so besides this being the wrong place in the file for a function declaration, you can't interpret this as a function declaration because it tries to use a function call as the name of a parameter.

Conversely, if you try to interpret this line as a function call to a function named `waitpid` (that's already defined), `getpid("apt-get")` makes sense as a parameter because it means you want to pass the result of the `getpid` function as the first parameter to the `waitpid` function. However, the rest of that line is incorrect syntax for a function call, because the types of the parameters to a function call should not be specified inline - you should be passing it parameters that have already been defined as variables or functions. A syntactically-correct call to the `waitpid` function might look like this:

```
int* statusPtr = ...;
int WUNTRACED = ...;
pid_t myPid = waitpid(getpid("apt-get"), &statusPtr, WUNTRACED);
```

And the following definition might appear elsewhere:

```
pid_t waitpid(pid_t pid, int *statusPtr, int WUNTRACED) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It looks more like a function *declaration* (a definition includes the body of the function, `{ ... }`). But the `pid_t getpid("apt-get")` isn't a valid parameter declaration, so the whole thing is just a syntax error.